# Leap year exercise (Chris Pine): Help/review

Tags: ruby

I'm brand new to programming and just working through the "Leap Year" exercise on Chris Pine's site.

1. Is including the following code in my while loop the correct way to approach this?

   ```
   and start = start.to_i + 1
   ```
2. I can't get the program to `puts` the first year in my list if it is a leap year too.

```
puts 'Enter start year...'
start = gets.chomp

puts 'Enter end year...'
last = gets.chomp

puts 'Your leap year selection...'

while start.to_i <= last.to_i and start = start.to_i + 1
    if (start % 4 == 0 and start % 100 != 0) or (start % 100 == 0 and 
        start > % 400 == 0)
        puts start
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question with a link to the exercise in question? Or explain what this is trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

First off, your code doesn't run because it doesn't always remember to use `start.to_i` to use the string `start` as a number. Rather than constantly having to do the conversion, convert it immediately. As a rule of thumb, cleaning up your data early will make the code simpler.

```
puts 'Enter start year...'
start = gets.chomp.to_i

puts 'Enter end year...'
last = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Now `start` and `last` are numbers... hold on, `start` and `last`? Make that `start` and `end` or `first` and `last`. Good name are important. I expect you tried `end` and it didn't work because it's a keyword. So `first` and `last`.

---

Let's look at this.

```
while first <= last and first = first + 1
    ...
end
```

What that's trying to do is iterate from `first` to `last`. The problem is `first <= last and first = first + 1` is evaluated even before the loop runs, so `first` has already been incremented. That's why you're not getting the first year.

You *could* fix that by putting the incrementing at the end of the loop.

```
while first <= last
    ...
    first = first + 1
end
```

Now it checks `first <= last`, does a leap year calculation, and only then does it increment `first`.

But that style of looping is typically avoided in Ruby. Instead, Ruby provides a [range operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) to iterate over. Once you have a range, you can call the [`each` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-each) on it to loop through each element.

```
(first..last).each do |year|
    ...
end
```

Each number from `first` to `last` will be assigned to `year`. Then the rest of your code works fine!

```
(first..last).each do |year|
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0)   or
       (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0)
        puts year
    end
end
```

Comment: Additionally, `and` and `or` are usually frowned upon, in favour of `&&` and `||`, except one is using them as flow control, because their different precedence used to be a common source of errors.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Welcome to Programming and StackoverFlow. I hope you will have your utmost joy throughout your journey :).

As for the exercise, 
Your approach is correct, but you made a mistake with

```
while start.to_i <= last.to_i and start = start.to_i + 1
```

This expression is an assignment:

```
start = start.to_i + 1
```

which increments the value of this variable and skips checking for the first value.

You can do that incrementation inside the while loop body instead:

2. You test if the first year is a leap year by incrementing it only after you have done an initial check:

   ```
    puts 'Enter start year...'
    start = gets.chomp

    puts 'Enter end year...'
    last = gets.chomp

    puts 'Your leap year selection...'

    while start.to_i <= last.to_i 
      if (start % 4 == 0 and start % 100 != 0) or (start % 100 == 0 and 
    start > % 400 == 0)
       puts start
      end
     start = start.to_i + 1
    end
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: "*The while syntax does not allow you to put assignments in its conditional part.*" Note, that is not correct. I believe its Python that deliberately disallows assignment in a while condition. AFAIK you can use any expression as the condition in Ruby, and it can include assignments. The result of the expression will be used as the condition. Assigning in conditionals is normal, like `while line = getline()`, but unnecessary in languages like Ruby which have good iterators.

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for your information. In Ruby, everything besides null and false have the value _true_. That is why even an assignment can be evaluated as a boolean value.

Comment: @Schwern: A bit more precisely, Ruby will warn against an assignment in a conditional if the assignment is of a certain type (I think a constant value on the right side), but generally has no problems with them: `puts a if a = 1` is bad, `puts a if a = b` is okay.